# List of all Windows VMs under all subscriptions under a single Tenant

Tags: powershell, powershell-az-module

I want to write a script (preferably PowerShell calling the Az cli modules) that lists of all Windows VMs (whether allocated or de-allocated), subscription, resource-group, vm-name, the os system, the OS version, latest patch information under all Azure subscriptions under a single Azure Tenant. Want this in table format.

There are a number of scripts on the internet but use the 'old' Az modules.

I need help in identifying the Az modules to use and fields to query.

My high level pseudo logic.

```
$tenant_id = xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx
$subscription_array = Get-All-Subcriptions -tenant $tenant_id

for(each $sub in $subscription_array)
{
   $vm_array = Get-Windows-Vms -subscription $sub

   for(each $vm in $vm_array)
   {
          $vm_name = $vm.name        
          $vm_os = $vm.os        -- Windows-2019, Windows_server-2012 etc...
          $vm_rg  = $vm.resource_group
          $vm_patch_version = $vm.latest_patch_no 
    
          $collection_of_vm_records.add($vm_name, $vm_os, $vm_rg, $vm_patch_version)  
   }   
  
}

Write $collection_of_vm_records to csv file
```

Comment: az account subscription list = Get all subscriptions for a tenant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you both windows and linux vm's details.

```
$report = @()
 $subs = Get-AzSubscription
 Foreach ($sub in $subs)
     {
     select-AzSubscription $sub | Out-Null
     $subName = $sub.Name
        
     $vms = Get-AzVM
     $publicIps = Get-AzPublicIpAddress 
     $nics = Get-AzNetworkInterface | Where-Object { $_.VirtualMachine -NE $null} 
     foreach ($nic in $nics) { 
         $info = "" | Select-Object VmName, ResourceGroupName, Region, VmSize, VirtualNetwork, PrivateIpAddress, OsType, PublicIPAddress, Subscription, Cores, Memory, CreatedDate
         $vm = $vms | ? -Property Id -eq $nic.VirtualMachine.id 
         foreach($publicIp in $publicIps) { 
             if($nic.IpConfigurations.id -eq $publicIp.ipconfiguration.Id) {
                 $info.PublicIPAddress = $publicIp.ipaddress
                 } 
             } 
             [string]$sku = $vm.StorageProfile.ImageReference.Sku
             [string]$os = $vm.StorageProfile.ImageReference.Offer
             $osDiskName = $vm.StorageProfile.OsDisk.Name
             $info.VMName = $vm.Name 
             $info.OsType = $os + " " + $sku
             $info.ResourceGroupName = $vm.ResourceGroupName 
             $info.Region = $vm.Location
             $vmLocation = $vm.location 
             $info.VmSize = $vm.HardwareProfile.VmSize
             $info.VirtualNetwork = $nic.IpConfigurations.subnet.Id.Split("/")[-3] 
             $info.PrivateIpAddress = $nic.IpConfigurations.PrivateIpAddress 
             $info.Subscription = $subName
             if ($vmLocation)
                 {
                 $sizeDetails = Get-AzVMSize -Location $vmLocation | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $vm.HardwareProfile.VmSize}
                 }
             $info.Cores = $sizeDetails.NumberOfCores
             $info.Memory = $sizeDetails.MemoryInMB
             $osDisk = Get-AzDisk -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName -DiskName $osDiskName
             $info.CreatedDate = $osDisk.TimeCreated
             $report+=$info
             } 
     }
 $csv = $report | Select-Object VmName, ResourceGroupName, Region, VmSize, VirtualNetwork, PrivateIpAddress, OsType, PublicIPAddress, Subscription, Cores, Memory, CreatedDate
 $csv | Export-Csv C:\temp\Inventory.csv -NoTypeInformation
```